# WPF TCP Server Listener Stops listening after a period of time

Tags: wpf, tcp

I have created a TCP server Listener which works to listen for some IOT Devices being connected as TCP Clients.

The TCP server listener would be working for several hours and sometimes for a full day then suddenly it stops listening. I just use to turn off and on the WPF application then it start working for the same amount of time and scenario keeps going on the same.

would you Please take a look to my code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TcpListener _TcpListener;
    private TcpClient _TcpClient;

    private bool _IsRun = false;
    private int countRows = 0;
    protected NetworkStream _NetStream;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textPort.Text.Trim()))
        {
            int port = Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text.Trim());
            _TcpListener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            _TcpListener.Start();
            _IsRun = true;
            this.btnListener.IsEnabled = false;
            Print("Listener (" + port + ") was started");
            new Task(() => {
                while (_IsRun)
                {
                    if (_TcpClient == null)
                    {
                        _TcpClient = _TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                        Print("A new connected! remote:" + _TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                        _NetStream = _TcpClient.GetStream();
                    }
                    if (_TcpClient.Connected && _NetStream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = null;
                        buffer = new byte[_TcpClient.Available];
                        _NetStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).Replace("-", "");
                        string asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).Trim('\0');
                        Print("HEX:" + hexString + " ASCII:" + asciiString);
                        //this method will receive the Byte data
                        Analysis(buffer);
                    }
                }
            }).Start();
        }
        
    }

    private void Print(string msg)
    {
        if (countRows > 10)
        {
            this.textLog.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.textLog.Document.Blocks.Clear();
            }));

            countRows = 0;
        }
        msg = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "： " + msg + "\r";
        this.textLog.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.textLog.AppendText(msg);
            this.textLog.ScrollToEnd();
            countRows += 1;
        }));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Impossible to know for sure without a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Also impossible to know for sure without a better problem description than _"stops listening"_. What does that mean? How do you determine it _"stops listening"_? What are the symptoms _exactly_? All that said, assuming the code is okay (maybe it is, maybe it isn't), could just be a network configuration issue.

Comment: What I mean by stop listening is that, I have programmed the application to print out  in textLog once data has been received. The application will operate as normal and will receive and print the incoming data for several hours, then no more data won't be print anymore  in the textLog  which makes an assumption that listener sever stops after a period of time. I have tried closing the app and started it and it start again receiving the data as normal then the same situation happened after  several hours. I have included all my application code up

Comment: _"which makes an assumption that listener sever stops after a period of time"_ -- ah, so you don't actually _know_ anything about whether the server has stopped listening. Just because your program stops doing what it's supposed to, you can't just assuming that's because of one specific thing among all the possible things that might cause that. You'll need to debug this yourself so that you know _exactly_ where the problem is, and/or provide a proper [mcve] that will reliably reproduce the problem so that you can post a question with that here.